# wrapper moves right if I add css: top

Tags: html, css, debugging, label

when I add top style rule my wrapper goes down but also left, i don't understand it, please help me.

[JS Fiddle click me](https://jsfiddle.net/h2ouyeyx/)

```
.svg[for="nav-trigger"] {
position: absolute;
color:white;
height: 13px;
width: 16px;
background-image: url(../assets/menu.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
right: 0; top: 0;
margin: 30px 30px 0 0;
z-index: 2;
cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-trigger + .site-wrap {
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
 }
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
 top: 80%;
 }
```

Thank you,
Tim4497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, It's not really your wrapper moving but your whole html. That margin is the width of the scroll bar that is not showing.

if insteed of using `overflow-x: hidden;` on body you just use `overflow: hidden;` it will be fixed but I don't know if that will generate other problems for you as we don't know what your final results are going to be

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80%;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, works in the window, but not in the full Chrome browser it seeks.  Works in other browsers though

Comment: An explanation of the problem and your solution would be helpful.